# Remove doublon for an array of objects by object property

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object like this one (sorted by ascending timestamp) :

```
[
 {id: 'o3134432S2', tot: '45', type: 'dynamic', timestamp: '2018-04-03'},
 {id: '3566543aa3', tot: '34', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-03'},
 {id: '4530134a97', tot: '34', type: 'gold', timestamp: '2018-04-04'},
 {id: '234554b333', tot: '42', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-04'},
 {id: '2463545633', tot: '55', type: 'dynamic', timestamp: '2018-04-05'},
 {id: '5654324566', tot: '13', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-06'}
]
```

This array may be really long (more than a thousand values), and there may be for each day 1 gold, 1 saved, or both.
I want to remove doublons for each day, giving priority to saved ones if present.
In my case, that would return :

```
[
 {id: '3566543aa3', tot: '34', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-03'},
 {id: '234554b333', tot: '42', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-04'},
 {id: '2463545633', tot: '55', type: 'dynamic', timestamp: '2018-04-05'},
 {id: '5654324566', tot: '13', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-06'}
]
```

I've done something using lots of while and foreach, but it takes from 5 to 30 seconds and I'm pretty sure it could be way faster.

```
    function remouveDoublon(originalArray) {
    const filteredSaved = originalArray.filter(forecast => {forecast.type === "saved" })

    const filteredDynamic = forecastProductOrders.filter((forecast) => { return forecast.type === 'dynamic' })
    let exists = false;
    if (filteredSaved.length > 0) {
        filteredSaved.forEach(forecast => {
            exists = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < filteredDynamic.length; i++) {
                if (moment(filteredDynamic[i].timestamp).isSame(moment(forecast.timestamp), 'day') && filteredDynamic[i].supplierProductId === forecast.supplierProductId) {
                    filteredDynamic[i].tot = forecast.tot;
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (exists === false) {
                let objToPush = forecast;
                objToPush.type === 'saved';
                filteredDynamic.push(objToPush);
            }
        })
    }
    return filteredDynamic
}
```

Has anyone an idea on how to make this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: please add what you have, and we have a look to the code.

Comment: is the data sorted?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes sorted by ascending timestamp

Comment: @NinaScholz I've added the code I have ATM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Array#Reduce` . Filter the array with timestamp .Then if exist same timestamp in new array compare type .Then added saved type object only

```js
var arr = [
 {id: 'o3134432S2', tot: '45', type: 'gold', timestamp: '2018-04-03'},
 {id: '3566543aa3', tot: '34', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-03'},
 {id: '4530134a97', tot: '34', type: 'gold', timestamp: '2018-04-04'},
 {id: '234554b333', tot: '42', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-04'},
 {id: '2463545633', tot: '55', type: 'gold', timestamp: '2018-04-05'},
 {id: '5654324566', tot: '13', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-06'}
];

arr = arr.reduce(function(a,b){
    var ind = a.map(i=>i.timestamp).indexOf(b.timestamp);
    if(ind == -1){
     a.push(b);
    }else{
     a[ind] =  a[ind]['type'] == 'saved'? a[ind]:b;
    }
   return a;
},[])
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the array and save each entry in a dict by using the date as a key. if the entry is already present check the type and update it only if it is 'saved'. Then transform the dict into a list again. This would have a linear runtime. Maybe something like this

```
unique = {}
for entry in entries:
    if unique[entry.date] and unique[entry.date].type == "saved":
         continue
    unique[entry.date] = entry

print(list(unique))
```

Comment: That would be easy, the issue is that if there's no saved for a day but there's a dynamic, then I must put the dynamic one

Comment: I am not sure if I get it correctly, but I would check if the date is already set, if not add it anyway, otherwise check if the type is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method and then sort it my timestamp again if you want.

```js
const data = [
 {id: 'o3134432S2', tot: '45', type: 'dynamic', timestamp: '2018-04-03'},
 {id: '3566543aa3', tot: '34', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-03'},
 {id: '4530134a97', tot: '34', type: 'gold', timestamp: '2018-04-04'},
 {id: '234554b333', tot: '42', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-04'},
 {id: '2463545633', tot: '55', type: 'dynamic', timestamp: '2018-04-05'},
 {id: '5654324566', tot: '13', type: 'saved', timestamp: '2018-04-06'}
]
let result = data.filter(o => o.type === 'saved')
data.filter(o => o.type !== 'saved').forEach(g => {
  if (result.filter(r => r.timestamp === g.timestamp).length === 0) result.push(g)
})
console.log(result)
```